# Why is my TextField and List not showing when both are together in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have just started learning flutter this week!, After following a 5 hour video I decided that I would be a good Idea to work on a to do list using my knowledge. I have been having some problems with the layout order because I am used to react native and html. So I have a TextField in which a user can type the a task and then submit it so that it can appear on a list of the added tasks which is below this textfield. In the process I realized that the code is not displaying anything. The code just shows something if the TextField is removed or the list is removed but it looks that they cant be in the same page. How can I fix that problem?

My current code which doesnt display anything (main.dart)

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> _toDoItems = [];

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.length > 0) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(task);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(toDoText)
    );
  }

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
          return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index]);
        }
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text('To Do List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          )
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  onSubmitted: (val) {
                    _addToDoItem(val);
                  },
                ),
            ), _buildToDoList(),
            
          ],
        ),
    
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the following code is the one that does display the list but not the TextField

```
body:  _buildToDoList(),
```

code that does display the TextField but not the List

```
body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  onSubmitted: (val) {
                    _addToDoItem(val);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Add a tak here...',
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ), // the list widget here is removed so that the text field could appear
            
          ],
        ),
```

for button next to text field:

```
body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: Row(children: [
                  TextField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    onSubmitted: (val) {
                      _addToDoItem(val);
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Add a tak here...',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.5),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('ADD'),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ],)
                
            ), 
            _buildToDoList(),    
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` 
code snippet

```
Widget _buildToDoList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index]);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> _toDoItems = [];

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if (task.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _toDoItems.add(task);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(toDoText));
  }

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index]);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
            child: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              title: Text(
                'To Do List',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
              child: TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                onSubmitted: (val) {
                  _addToDoItem(val);
                },
              ),
            ),
            _buildToDoList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

full code 2

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> _toDoItems = [];

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if (task.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _toDoItems.add(task);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(toDoText));
  }

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index]);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
            child: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              title: Text(
                'To Do List',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: TextField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        onSubmitted: (val) {
                          _addToDoItem(val);
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Add a tak here...',
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                            borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.5),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('ADD'),
                        onPressed: null,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            _buildToDoList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Just one question, Why did wraping the list in an `Expanded` widget worked?

Comment: ListView need to know size height / width.you can provide size with Container or SizeBox. with Expaneded you can take current available size.

Comment: ohh that makes sense now, one last question. I tried adding a reised button at the right side of the TextField wrapping that Text container and new Button Container to Row widget but the code didnt worked, Why?

Comment: your code works fine. I have post full code 2 and picture. do you encounter any error?

Comment: Yes that works, I meant the button next to the text field that doesnt work. I added that code at the last part of the question

Comment: you can use Expaned flex, see updated full code 2. change flex to take available space size